# Use Data from Fitbit HR in Android Application

Tags: android, fitbit

I am developing a medical app. In my application I would like to get the Heartrate data from the Fitbit HR. I have been looking at the fitbit API docs on : https://wiki.fitbit.com/display/API/Fitbit+API  however the following methods have been deprecated API-Get-Heart-Rate. Is there a third party library I can use.

Answer (score 2):

Fitbit does not support heart rate yet. The old commands are deprecated and won't work with new devices. See announcement here:
https://wiki.fitbit.com/display/API/Fitbit+API